# IConfigurationBuilder SetBasePath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, appsettings

I am struggling with my API configuration.

Using NET Core 3.1, debugging using IIS Express.

I never realized the default path for the `appsettings.json` is the root of the project even in the debug mode. The file provider always reads from the `C:\MyProject\` directory.

I got to a situation where one of our config files is coming from a NuGet package and as such, it is copied to the `bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1` folder. But I am not able to load the file.

I tried to set the ContentRoot or BasePath, but I am getting unexpected results.

If the path points to `bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1`, the file provider ignores that and still searches in the root of the project.

If I add a folder to any of the current directory sources, the file provider starts to look in the `C:\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\{fodler name}` folder.

The code will probably work in runtime, but I have difficulties running my code in debug mode.

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
    {
        // tried many combinations here using Path.Combine() with Directory, Environment, HostingContext, AppContext
        // nothing worked to set the path to the bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1 folder
        config.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        config.AddJsonFile("default.json");
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        // also tried to set the content root, with the same results
        webBuilder.UseContentRoot("./bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1");
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

I am confused and do not understand from where the problem comes.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Yes, see the answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the right way to do that is to set the content root.
The code below works for me.

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("default.json");
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseContentRoot(".");
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Comment: I added content root, but still the same error